# Not able to login to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: login, ubuntu-12.04, vmware-player

I am using VMPlayer to run ubuntu 12.04 as a guest OS with host being Windows 7.
When I try to login to my account it says that the password is not correct.
However, if I switch to console mode by hitting Ctrl + Alt + F2 I am able to login
successfully. 
Removing the ~/.Xauthority file as suggested in some threads did not help.

Additional info: I recently created a new user - login problems started after that.
At the login page the name of the user is surrounded by curly braces.

Thank you very much in advance.